# Request objects causing memory leaks

Tags: scrapy

just a quick question. I am facing problems with scrapy using too much memory. The documentation shows an example with **HtmlResponse** objects lasting for as long as **Request** objects, and uses this argument to conclude that **HtmlResponse** objects are causing a memory leak. My question is, what about **Request** objects? shouldn't they not last as long too?

The following is my prefs() output:

`Spider             1   oldest: 353s ago
Request        46544   oldest: 338s ago
HtmlResponse       9   oldest: 3s ago`

Comment: If you pass a reference to a `Request` in the `meta` of new `Request`, the referred `Request` will be bound to the life of the new `Request`. So yes, `Request` objects could live for a long time. https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/leaks.html#common-causes-of-memory-leaks